# How to Iterate the contents of multidimentional array in parallel using Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I have an array containing number of array. I am trying to get the element from each array parallely. Can some body please help me.

```
@shuffle= (
       [ "george", "jane", "elroy" ],
       [ "homer", "marge", "bart" ],
       [ "fred", "barney" ]
);
```

I tried this, but it iterating the inner arrays sequentially.

```
my @fh;
#create an array of open filehandles.
@fh = map { @$_ } @shuffle;

foreach (@fh){
    my $line = $_;
    print $line."\n";

}
```

And out put is like this :

```
george
jane
elroy
homer
marge
bart
fred
barney
```

But I need the output like this :

```
george
homer 
fred   
jane
marge
barney
elroy
bart
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you need to bear in mind is when perl does an 'array of arrays' it's actually an array of array references.

What you're doing with your `map` there is dereferencing each in turn, and by doing so 'flattening' your array - taking all the elements in the first array reference, then the second and so on.

But that's not what you're trying to accomplish - you're trying to take the *first* element from each, then second, then third etc.

But what that map statement does do is allow you to count the total number of elements in your array, which can be used thus:

```
my @shuffle= (
       [ "george", "jane", "elroy" ],
       [ "homer", "marge", "bart" ],
       [ "fred", "barney" ]
);

while ( map { @$_ } @shuffle ) { 
    foreach my $sub_array ( @shuffle ) { 
       print shift @$sub_array // '',"\n"; 
    }
}
```

that's probably not an ideal way to test if you're finished though - but it does allow you to have varying lengths of inner arrays

Comment: Good catch. Can you explain what is the meaning of `//` in your `print` statement. I modified the statement like `print shift @$sub_array ,"\n"; `. It is also gives the same result., Why you actually using this.? What is the good reason behind this?

Comment: It's the `defined` operator - it works like `||` - it means when you try and shift your empty array (the last one, for the last element) you get `''` instead of `undef`ined.

Comment: Ya got it. Without using this it reports the warnings when using use warnings.  Thank you for you clear explanation :)

Comment: *"The thing you need to bear in mind is when Perl does an 'array of arrays' it's actually an array of array references"* This sort of thing is said a lot but I believe it's misleading. There is no machine-level representation of multi-dimensional arrays, and apologising that Perl has to use references is detrimental to the adoption of the language. C does it by requiring that the second dimension has a constant size and doing the arithmetic for you if you write `array[34][56]`. Likewise, Perl will fetch the correct element of a 2D array if you write `$array[34][56]`

Comment: I don't see it as apologising.  I find it an easier way understanding what's happening. That's all.

Comment: @Sobrique: That's fine. But your words echo those of others that are clearly concessions. I suggest that you drop stuff like *actually* and use phrases like *implemented as*. It's best if new users think of 2D arrays as 2D arrays, especially when *autovivication* helps our pretence!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `each_arrayref` function from the [`List::MoreUtils`](http://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils) module.

The code would look like this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::MoreUtils qw/ each_arrayref /;

use Data::Dump;

my @shuffle = (
    [ qw/ george jane    elroy / ],
    [ qw/ homer  marge   bart /  ] ,
    [ qw/ fred   barney / ],
);

my $iter = each_arrayref @shuffle;

while ( my @set = $iter->() ) {
    dd \@set;
}
```

### output

```
["george", "homer", "fred"]
["jane", "marge", "barney"]
["elroy", "bart", undef]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
my @shuffle= (
       [ "george", "jane", "elroy" ],
       [ "homer", "marge", "bart" ],
       [ "fred", "barney" ]
);

for my $i(0..$#shuffle)
{
    for my $j(0..$#shuffle)
    {
        print "$shuffle[$j][$i]\n";
    }   
}
```