# Printing "Multi-Dimensional" Array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, dereference, perl-data-structures

I am having a problem attempting to print an array that contains arrays. When printing the array `@dev` which contains the other arrays, I am only managing to print the first three as it is indicated by the `#printing` in-line comments. The commented line `#print($dev[4][2]);` works fine, as well as any of the other combination of numbers within the allowable range. For some reason the for loop does not work. Help!?

```
my @dev;
my @tf;
my @a;
my @t;
my @f;
my @ofv;
my @tfv;

@tf = ('123456787', '123456788', '123456789'); #printing
@a = (78, 65, 57); #printing
@t = (70, 55, 42); #printing
@f = (77, 64, 56);
@ofv = ('true', 'false', 'false');
@tfv = ('false', 'true', 'true');       

@dev = (
    [@tf],
    [@a],
    [@t],
    [@f],
    [@ofv],
    [@tfv],
);

#print($dev[4][2]);

for (my $i = 0; $i <= (scalar(@tf) - 1); $i++) {
    for (my $j = 0; $j <= (scalar(@dev) - 1); $j++) {
        print($dev[$i][$j]);
        print("\n");
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529090/how-to-iterate-the-contents-of-multidimentional-array-in-parallel-using-perl/34529824#34529824 user Sobrique and user Borodin answers will help for you.

Comment: Instead of `scalar(@t)-1` it's generally better to use `$#t` which is the index of the last element.

Answer (score 3):

Perl can be quite compact.
This snippet of code do the same thing for my arrays @arr1, @arr2 and @arr3:

```
@arr1 = (1..10);
@arr2 = ('a'..'j');
@arr3 = ('.') x 10;

@multid = \(@arr1, @arr2, @arr3);
print "@$_\n" for (@multid);
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
a b c d e f g h i j
. . . . . . . . . .
```

Also the `[]` copies an array and gives a reference to it (It's an anonymous array in memory, regardless of the array, a copy of which he is). If there is no need to such duplicate, it is better to use the backslash `\` which instead gives a reference to existing array without coping. (like `&` operator in C, as tell us perldoc)

Comment: you can use the `()x` repeat operator: `@arr3 = ('.') x 10;`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to show the data of such complex data struct, the modules [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) or [Smart::Comments](http://p3rl.org/Smart::Comments) may be good options.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@dev);
```

or

```
use Smart::Comments;
### @dev
```

The output is much more perl-style and not that readable, but is quite convenient to show the struct of such complex data.

Comment: Actually [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer) is way nicer for inspecting than Data::Dumper, as the latter is meant to produce machine-readable output.

Answer (score 1):

Your outermost for loop is constrained by the length of t, which is 3. It will never print more than three arrays.

If I understand what you're trying to do, you need top swap @t and @dev. That will print all your values.

That won't, however, print any array that is longer than 3 (the length of dev).

For that, you need:

```
@dev = (
    [@tf], # Probably meant tf
    [@a],
    [@t],
    [@f],
    [@ofv],
    [@tfv],
);

#print($dev[4][2]);

for (my $i = 0; $i < @dev; $i++) {
    for (my $j = 0; $j < @{ $dev[$i] }; $j++) {
        print($dev[$i][$j]);
        print("\n");
    }
}
```